# how to configure datatable plugin in a dynamic table rows create through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I am fetching data through Mysql database. The data is large so I am using datatable plugin to create pagination below the table. Datatable plugin working fine with static table but when I configure it to my dynamic data table it is not working. I have no idea how to implement this.

Here is my ajax file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $name = $_GET['name'];
$query = mysql_query("select id,card_name,phone1,address,region,country,cert_num,category_cod,material_cod,trade_type,web from pdbp inner join bp on(pdbp.bp_id=bp.id) where bp.status= 1 and card_name like '%$name%'");

 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $id = $data['id'];
     $name = $data['card_name'];
     $phone1 = $data['phone1'];
     $region = $data['region'];
     $trade_type = $data['trade_type'];
     $web = $data['web']; 
     $country = $data['country'];
     $cat = $data['category_cod'];
     $mat = $data['material_cod'];


     $retval=$retval."<tr><td>".++$counter."</td><td> ".$name." </td><td> ".$phone1." </td><td> ".$region." </td><td> ".$cat." </td><td> ".$mat." </td><td> ".$trade_type."</td><td> ".$web."</td></tr>";
 }

echo $retval;
}
?>
```

and here is my second file:

```
<table id="datatables" border="1">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sr No.</th>
                                <th>
                                    Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Telephone
                                </th>

                                <th>
                                    Categories
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Material
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Type
                                </th>
                                <th> Website </th>


                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="datas">

                            </tbody>
                            </table>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatables').DataTable()

    $("#cmp_name").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
             'url':"filter.php",
            'data':{name:$("#cmp_name").val()},
            'method':'GET',
            'success':function(name){

                 $("#datas").html(name);            
            }
        })

  });

});

</script>
```

How can I integrate datatable plugin?

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway look at the DataTables documentation, it has examples of how to integrate ajax functionality into it. You can just return JSON from the server, and DataTables will do the rest. Right now you're just ignoring all the nice functionality that DataTables offers, and might as well not bother using it. I also wouldn't advocate launching a new request every time the user presses a key. Maybe wait until they enter at 3 characters or something, or just wait till they finish typing

Comment: @ADyson I go through the documentation but I am unable to configure it to my code.

Comment: In that case show what you tried, please, and explain what goes wrong / what errors you get. If you don't understand some specifics of the documentation, ask about that particular thing

Comment: I am not getting my pagination. I upload my ajax and html file. I want to know what I need to change in my ajax and html file so that I get my required results

Comment: You need to change most of it, is the short answer. You aren't doing this even vaguely like the documentation explains. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html, https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax, https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/ . Try to follow what's described, and post your updated attempt if you still have problems. And also switch your database code to mysqli or PDO urgently.